# How to make a library .a file linkable with gcc/g++

Tags: gcc, installation, linker, posix, static-libraries

When I want to compile something that uses, for example, libspotify I am able to link against the libspotify library by including the term `-lspotify` in the compilation command and then everything works.

If I am writing and installing my own library, where do I put the .a file (or in any case what do I do) to be able to link against my library in the same manner?

In case it matters, this question concerns Posix systems. For the moment I am not interested in how this is done in Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your library anywhere as long as the linker (`ld`) knows where to look
for it.

How does the linker know where to look for libraries?

You can tell it where to look by one or more occurrences of the commandline option
`-L<directory>`.

If you link with the options

```
-L/look/here/first -L/look/here/second -lfoo
```

then `ld` with look for a library, `libfoo.so` (shared) or `libfoo.a` (static), first in
`/look/here/first`; failing that in `/look/here/second`; failing that
it will look through a configured list of default places, and failing any of
them it will fail, complaining that it cannot find `-lfoo`. Although the order of the
`-L` options matters, the order of the `-l` options with respect to the `-L options
doesn't matter:

```
-lfoo -L/look/here/first -L/look/here/second
```

has just the same meaning.

Once it has found `libfoo` somewhere the linker looks no further, and in each directory
where it looks, by default it looks for `libfoo.so` before it looks for `libfoo.a`.

Usually we do not link by invoking `ld` directly. We link by invoking one
of the language-specific tool drivers, `gcc`, `g++`, `gfortran`, etc., passing
it options that direct it to do linking, and not pre-processing or compiling.
In this case, the tool driver invokes `ld` on our behalf, and behind the scenes
appends additional linker options which are invariant for the language
in question, saving us from having to remember and repeat boilerplate on our commandlines.

`ld` itself, however, has a built-in list of default `-L` directories for each architecture
that it supports. These are configured by whoever built your `ld`, usually your distro,
in which case you'll find that the default places are the directories where libraries
are conventionally installed by your distro's package manager.

Thus, if you want to link a library that is in one of the default places you don't 
need to specify any `-L` options yourself. `-lfoo` will do.

Conversely, if you want to be able to link `libfoo.a` simply
by mentioning `-lfoo` on the linkage commandline, then you need to put it in
one of the linker's default places. And if you want to distribute `libfoo.a` in such
a way that other users can link it in the same way, then you need to distribute
it in a package that will install it in one of the default places (on the target
system, whatever it may be).

For that, you need to know what the default places are. For Posix systems,
you can depend on `/usr/local/lib`, `/lib` and `/usr/lib`. But don't install in `/lib`. 
That's  reserved for vital system libraries. To see what the linker's default search 
directories actually are on your own system, you can run:

```
gcc -m64 -Xlinker --verbose  2>/dev/null | grep SEARCH_DIR
```

and it will emit something like:

```
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"); \
SEARCH_DIR("=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"); \
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"); \
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib64"); \
SEARCH_DIR("=/lib64"); \
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib64"); \
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/local/lib"); \
SEARCH_DIR("=/lib"); \
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/lib"); \
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64"); \
SEARCH_DIR("=/usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib");
```

telling you that those directories are default `-L`-options, in that order.
Notice that you have to choose the 64/32-bit flavour of linkage that you
are concerned about. Replace `-m64` with `-m32` and you'll get something
different. The portably Posix options, excluding `/lib`, are `/usr/local/lib` and `/usr/lib`.

That answers your question, but you're not finished. Presumably, your library 
comes with one or more header files through which programs can import its API.
If the library is going to be in the linker's default search path, then the header(s)
had better be in the *compiler's* default search path, so that programs can
just `#include <foo.h>` or maybe `#include <foo/bar.h>` and have the compiler 
find the header without you having to write `-I/foo/headers/are/here` in the compiler commandline.

To see the compiler's default search path, for C, run:

```
echo | gcc -xc -E -v -
```

The relevant bit of output will be something like:

```
 #include "..." search starts here:
 #include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
```

or for C++:

```
echo | gcc -xc++ -E -v -
```

showing, e.g.:

```
 #include "..." search starts here:
 #include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/include/c++/5
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/5
 /usr/include/c++/5/backward
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/include-fixed
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
```

Chiming with the case for libraries, the portably Posix options
for headers are `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/include`.

So it's a choice between `/usr/local/{include|lib}` and `/usr/{include|lib}`. But consider that by
installing your files under `/usr/{include|lib}` you will be changing the 
inventory of your distro's libraries and header files in a manner not controlled
by its package management system. If it was, say, Debian 8.2, it won't be any more. 
Once you start doing this, and once you make a false step and break your packages, 
it's entirely your problem.

Unix and Linux have a convention for the installation of software that you build
yourself or from source packages uncontrolled by your distro's package management
system, that wisely defends the stability of your distribution. The convention is:
install it in `/usr/local/{include|bin|lib}`. That's exactly what `/usr/local` is
for.

Bottom line: Install your library under `/usr/local/lib` and your headers under
`/usr/local/include`. If you have multiple headers then prefer `/usr/local/include/foo`
and in program source write the like of `#include <foo/bar.h>`. Then you can
compile with no special `-I` options and link the library with no special `-L`
options, just `-lfoo`.

Comment: This answer is profoundly thorough. Not only does it answer my question but it will serve as a reference for me and (I think) many others. Thank you very much.